pathfit to scale to bound
I am creating svg path and scaling it to a specific dimension. Let's suppose 100x100. I am using d3 to shape the data as per my req.
However, I was wondering, how can I achieve the exact same output as pathStr with pathfit. This is what I tried below.


function degreeToRadian(d) {
    return (d * Math.PI) / 180;
};

function fnData() {
    const data = d3.range(0, 11, 1).map((d) => {
        const angleRadian = degreeToRadian(d);
        return {
            index: d,
            angleDeg: d,
            angleRadian: angleRadian,
            x: Math.cos(angleRadian),
            y: Math.sin(angleRadian)
        }
    });

    return data;
};

const width = 1280;
const height = 720;
const data = fnData();

//------------------------WITH D3------------------------//
const scaleX = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .range([0, 100])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.x));

const scaleY = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .range([100, 0])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.y));

const pathStr = d3
    .line()
    .x((d) => scaleX(d.x))
    .y((d) => scaleY(d.y))(data);
  
const pathStr2 = d3.line().x(d=>d.x).y(d=>d.y)(data);  

//------------------------WITH pathfit------------------------//

const base = {
    viewBox: `0 0 ${width} ${height}`,
    preserveAspectRatio: "xMidYMid meet" // the default
};
const pathFitter = new Pathfit(base, undefined, pathStr2).scale_with_aspect_ratio(100, 100);
console.log({d3:pathStr, pathfit:pathFitter});
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pathfit@1.0.4/pathfit.js"></script>




The transformed data from pathfit are tiny. Did you really mean to scale a 1280720 viewbox down to 100100, while the original data set has an extent of 0.0150.173? This results in the transformed data to only have a bounding box of 0.00110.0135, is this intended?

I am trying to figure out how pathfit can give me the exact same path string as const pathStr currently done through d3. if it can, I am definitely passing the wrong parameters to pathfit currently.

Ah, I had your question wrong. My first impression was you wanted a correction of the d3 result, not a correction of the pathfit result.

If you want to use the extent of your data as the box that should be expanded into the 100*100 dimensions, you have to set these data in the viewBox. d3 can provide you with the coordinates of the four sides:
const [x1, x2] = d3.extent(data, (d) => d.x);
const [y1, y2] = d3.extent(data, (d) => d.y);

viewBox: `${x1} ${y1} ${x2 - x1} ${y2 - y1}`

If you want to not preserve the aspect ratio, but stretch the data to the maximum dimensions in both directions, you have to set
preserveAspectRatio: "none"

If you want to flip the data upside-down, you have to provide a pretransform value. This is certainly a bit more awkward as with d3. Since SVG syntax is used, you can not specify a center of transformation directly, but need to find the correct formula for the transform matrix yourself. Fortunately, an upside-down flip that leaves the bounds of of your data exactly in place is relatively easy:
`matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 ${y1 + y2})`

Unfortunately, the result will still look different from what d3 delivers, because the non-scaled path string from d3 fed to pathfit has a too small number of digits after the decimal separator. This leads to rounding errors that appear huge in the end result. You will need to increase them from the default:
const pathStr2 = d3.line().digits(6).x(d=>d.x).y(d=>d.y)(data);



function degreeToRadian(d) {
    return (d * Math.PI) / 180;
};

function fnData() {
    const data = d3.range(0, 11, 1).map((d) => {
        const angleRadian = degreeToRadian(d);
        return {
            index: d,
            angleDeg: d,
            angleRadian: angleRadian,
            x: Math.cos(angleRadian),
            y: Math.sin(angleRadian)
        }
    });

    return data;
};

const width = 1280;
const height = 720;
const data = fnData();

//------------------------WITH D3------------------------//
const scaleX = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .range([0, 100])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.x));

const scaleY = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .range([100, 0])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, (d) => d.y));

const pathStr = d3
    .line()
    .x((d) => scaleX(d.x))
    .y((d) => scaleY(d.y))(data);
  
const pathStr2 = d3.line().digits(5).x(d=>d.x).y(d=>d.y)(data);  

//------------------------WITH pathfit------------------------//

const [x1, x2] = d3.extent(data, (d) => d.x);
const [y1, y2] = d3.extent(data, (d) => d.y);

const base = {
    viewBox: `${x1} ${y1} ${x2 - x1} ${y2 - y1}`,
    preserveAspectRatio: "none" // do stretch the result
};
const pathFitter = new Pathfit(
   base,
   undefined,
   pathStr2,
   `matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 ${y1 + y2})`,
   { precision: 4 }
).scale_with_aspect_ratio(100, 100);

console.log({d3:pathStr, pathfit:pathFitter});
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pathfit@1.0.4/pathfit.js"></script>




in a previous version of this answer, I thought the rounding error was caused by pathfit. That is not the case, see the edited answer.

Thanks for the answer. If I create a path that is data-driven, d3 can resolve my issue. But, not all the paths are data-driven. Hence, I was looking for a library that has an API to scale a path to a particular dimension. Is there any library you can suggest of?
